# AngularJS multiple expressions concatenating in interpolation with a URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, concatenation, interpolation

I know this is long, but please bear with me. The problem is easy to understand, just takes some writing to fully explain it.

Right now I'm getting this error

```
Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: 
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.  
See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce
```

I've done all the reading in the documentation, but I still can't find a workaround for my problem.

I'm using $http.get on a private online source that has data that is similar to the form of a json file (so I can't modify the data). The data looks like this:

```
...
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"N5Eg36Gl054SUNiWWc-Su3t5O-k/A7os41NAa_66TUu-1I-VxH70Rp0\"",
   "id": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoID": "MEoSax3BEms"
      },
   },
   {
    "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
    "etag": "\"N5Eg36Gl054SUNiWWc-Su3t5O-k/VsH9AmnQecyYBLJrl1g3dhewrQo\"",
    "id": {
       "kind": "youtube#video",
       "videoID": "oUBqFlRjVXU"
       },
    },
...
```

I'm trying to interpolate the videoId of each item into my HTML iframe that embeds the YouTube video. In my controller.js file, I'm setting the promise object after the $http.get as such

```
$http.get('privatesource').success(function(data) {
  $scope.videoList = data.items;
});
```

So now the variable "$scope.videoList" is mapped to data.items, which has a lot of video elements. In my HTML file, I can retrieve the videoID of each video by using

```
<ul class="videos">
  <li ng-repeat="video in videoList">
    <span>{{video.id.videoID}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this lists all the videoID's. 
But if I try to concatenate these values to a URL, like https://youtube.com/embed/, it does not work.

```
<div ng-repeat="video in videoList">
    <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" 
     ng-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video.id.videoId}}" 
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can get the videoID to be interpolated into the youtube URL? I've tried whitelisting by using the $sceDelegateProvider as follows but it still does not work

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
  'self',
  'https://www.youtube.com/**']);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since 1.2 you can only bind one expression to *[src], *[ng-src] or action. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to-src-ng-src-or-action-).

Try this instead:

In Controller:

```
$scope.getIframeSrc = function (videoId) {
  return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId;
};
```

HTML:

```
ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(video.id.videoId)}}"
```

Note that you still need to whitelist it as you have, or you will get `locked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy`.

Comment: +1 and thanks for your answer because all of the other answers relied on hard coding a URL as an $sce trusted resource, rather than populating it as a template item.

Comment: Thanks. How do you whitelist the url?

Comment: @molerat By injecting and using `$sceDelegateProvider` in the config block. For example: `$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'https://www.youtube.com/**']);`

Comment: @tasseKATT thank you - I just saw this was in the question already :)

Answer (score 81):

An alternative to @tasseKATT's answer (which doesn't require a controller function) is to use <strike>string concatenation directly in the expression</strike> a filter:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('youtubeEmbedUrl', function ($sce) {
    return function(videoId) {
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId);
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-src="{{ video.id.videoId | youtubeEmbedUrl }}"></div>
```

I've found this particularly useful when using SVG icon sprites, which requires you to use the `xlink:href` attribute on the SVG `use` tag - this is subject to the same SCE rules. Repeating the controller function everywhere I needed to use a sprite seemed silly so I used the filter method instead.

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('svgIconCardHref', function ($sce) {
    return function(iconCardId) {
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('#s-icon-card-' + iconCardId);
    };
  });
```

```html
<svg><use xlink:href="{{ type.key | svgIconCardHref }}"></use></svg>
```

Note: I had previously tried just simple string concatenation inside the expression. However this led to some unexpected behaviour where the browser would interpret the expression before Angular had a chance to parse it and replace with the real `href`. Since there is no `ng-src` equivalent for the `use` tag's `xlink:href` I opted for the filter, which seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It doesn't work if `xlink:href` have any string concatenation like `xlink:href="/path/to/something/{{ type.key | svgIconCardHref }}"`.

Comment: You could try putting the static string inside the curlies: `xlink:href="{{ '/path/to/something/' + (type.key | svgIconCardHref) }}"`

Answer (score 5):

in controller:

```
app.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
    };
}]);
```

in html:

```
ng-src="('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video.id.videoId) | trustAsResourceUrl"
```

Answer (score 0):

My version is `angular.min.1.5.8.js`
I had the same issue with a form. I resolved it by changing the attribute action=URL by ng-action=URL.

Note: this does not work because `ng-action` is not a real directive.