# concatenate expression into the mid of html tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoId}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In my View, how can I concatenate {{videoId}} into to my iframe tag?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: @ZXZpbGpvaG5pdXM I have tried that but I got Error while interpolating: http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{vidId}}
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required

Comment: Ah, perhaps this is relevant then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23406678/446030

And from it, the link to the relevant doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to-src-ng-src-or-action-

Answer (score 1):

First you should use `ngSource` to dynamically define the `src` attribute. Additionally you should use `$sce` to define it as trusted url:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.videoURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.youtube.com/embed/z6Ge6Op2mAk');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{videoURL}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```