# how to embed video link from database in iframe using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a url video links(   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myvideoid) from my database that i want to embed into i frame using angular.

i have tried the code below but its not working

```
<iframe width="200" height="300"  ng-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{v_link}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

where `{{v_link}}` is the column that stores the video in mysql database. any help please

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 2):

With [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) you can make the desired URL as [trusted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
});

app.filter('trustUrl', function($sce) {
  return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
  };
});

app.directive('youtubePlayer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      header: '@',
      video: '@'
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<iframe ng-src="{{video | trustUrl}}"></iframe>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.header = attrs.header;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS App</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <youtube-player video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZzlgJ-SfKYE" header="Url Description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </youtube-player>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error that you're getting is `$interpolate:noconcat`. It states:

> Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required. [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/noconcat).

This means that you must use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) and mark the desired URL as [trusted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl). **This would fix your problem:**

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($sce) {
    this.youtubeLink = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/N4ony2r0QFs');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{ vm.youtubeLink }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Another way, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405162/angularjs-multiple-expressions-concatenating-in-interpolation-with-a-url#answer-24807858), would be to create a custom filter which is specifically built to trust youtube URLs:

```
.filter('youtubeEmbedUrl', function ($sce) {
  return function(videoId) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId);
  };
});
```

You'd be using this filter anytime you want to embed a video, like this: `ng-src="{{ vm.youtubeLink | youtubeEmbedUrl }}"`.

Comment: Cosmin Ababei, the first code  does not show any video when run